# Filter objects based on expiry date using Q and "gt" Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have a model that it has an expiry field. This field can also be null. How can I return only object that either do not have expiry date or their expiry date is less than the current date?

this is my model:

```
class Buzz(models.Model):
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null = True)
    content = models.TextField(validators=[MaxLengthValidator(550)])
    author = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    expiry = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

I want something like:

```
now = timezone.now()
Buzz.objects.filter(Q(self.expiry__gt = now) | Q(self.expiry = null ))
```

But it's not returning the correct objects, how can I achieve this? I checked if the expiry field exists for some objects and it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should *not* use `self.`, furthermore `null` is not defined in Python either, `null` at the Django/Python layer is `None`. You can work with:

```
now = timezone.now()
Buzz.objects.filter(Q(expiry__gt=now) | Q(expiry=None))
```

It might be better to make use of the [**`Now()`** expression [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/database-functions/#now), then you can define the queryset once, and you do not to specify it again to "update" the `now`. `Now()` will use the database time:

```
from django.db.models.functions import Now
Buzz.objects.filter(Q(expiry__gt=Now()) | Q(expiry=None))
```